# Trying to find matching regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse mathematical expression using regex.

```
Input:  2--1 
Output: 2,-1
```

```
Input:  2+1 
Output: 2,1
```

Tried following but it works only for a+b scenario

```
Regex("[-|+]").split("2--1")
```

Comment: Maybe this works `[-|+](?!-|+)`

Comment: Give `[+-]?(-?\d+)` a try, if you don't care about the operator; otherwise put the first part in a separate capturing group. Also only works on whole numbers as per your example. Edit: Oh, d'oh - didn't see the split(). ^^

Comment: Do you want to split on a `+` or a `-` when the `-` is not preceded by `+` or `-`? Try `(?:\+|(?<![+-])-)` https://regex101.com/r/eTwKSi/1

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following regex.

```
(?<=\d)[+-]
```

you can also see the following link to view the result https://regex101.com/r/z8uUTf/1

Comment: Nice, you could even shorten it to `\b[+-]` depending on input composition.